# creating multiple elements with same set of options in zend framework.

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

Hi i have to create some multiselect element in zend with same options. i.e.

```
$B1 = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('Rating');
$B1->setLabel('B1Rating')
          ->setMultiOptions(
              array(
                  'NULL' => "Select", 
                  '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'))
          ->setRequired(TRUE)
          ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true);
    $B1->setValue(array('NULL'));
    $B1->size = 5;    
    $this->addElement($B1);
```

Now i have to create 5 elements of same type but different labels. So i don't want to copy the whole code 5 times. So is there any way i can do so without copy-pasting the code for 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About three different ways spring to mind. Here's the simplest one

```
$B2 = clone $B1;
$B2->setLabel('B2Rating');
```

Comment: see [docu](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) and look at the comments.

Comment: Hey thanks. Actually while looking at the shallow or deep cloning perspective i also found that we could use something like $form = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect(); ...... $new_form = $form->deepclone();

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
$options = array(
    'required'     => true,
    'validators'   => array('NotEmpty'),
    'value'        => null,
    'size'         => 5,
    'multiOptions' => array(
              'NULL' => "Select", 
              '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'),
);

$B1 = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('Rating', $options);
$B1->setLabel('B1Rating')
$this->addElement($B1);

$B2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('Rating2', $options);
$B2->setLabel('B2Rating')
$this->addElement($B1);
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

Because there's never a limit on the amount of ways you can accomplish a certain goal, here's another solution:

```
$ratingLabels = array('Rating 1', 'Rating 2', 'Rating 3');

foreach($ratingLabels as $index => $ratingLabel) {
    $this->addElement('multiselect', 'rating' . (++$index), array(
        'required' => true,
        'label' => $ratingLabel,
        'value' => 'NULL',
        'size' => 5,
        'multiOptions' => array(
            'NULL' => 'Select',
            '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'
        ),
    ));
}
```